# ASP.NET Routing a URL that does not contain a controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to direct the following URL:

```
http://myweburl/Wheel/466/Direction/903/Highlight/7
```

To a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int wheel, int direction, int highlight)
```

On the controller `VehicleController` I still want to keep my Home/Index as the root url of the site. So if someone entered

```
http://myweburl/
```

They would be directed to `Home/Index` How do I do this?

Comment: I've a suggestion for you. The parameters wheel, direction and highlight are different from each other. direction is not a category of wheel and highlight is not a category of direction. You could separate those items by '/' if those items have a relationship like category/item. I would suggest you to pass those values as querystrings instead of route parameters and by that way you are more RESTful.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the suggestion but this is just a contrived example, in my production code the parameters are related. (should of thought a bit more before posting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the follwing as a route above the default route (Home/Index)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WheelRoute",
    url: "Wheel/{wheel}/Direction/{direction}/Highlight/{highlight}",
    defaults: new { controller = "VehicleController", action = "Index" }
 );
```